# android include API 9 functionality in earlier API versions

Tags: java, android, sorting, data-structures, concurrency

Would like to keep the API level required for my application lower than the latest so it can be used on more devices, however I would like to incorporate some of the new concurrent data structures that are in API 9.  Of course, i could just write my own, but rather than re-invent the wheel, how to I pull in code / class / jar that has a sorting / sortable concurrent list / queue / set data structure.  I wanted to use ConcurrentSkipListSet but i really just want to be able to sort a concurrent list of objects using my custom comparator.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. If the new API functionality doesn't exist in earlier versions of the API, they don't exist. If you use them, you inject a dependency on the newer API.

Comment: Ken, maybe my question isn't clear...  I imagine that some of the funcationality in the API will not be able to be used, however for example, i used a Base64 class which i pulled in from other source code so i could use it prior to API 8 when it was introduced.  I would like to do the same with this as i want to use a concurrent sortable data construct and not have to write it from scratch.  I found this site: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-index.html which has code, but its a task in itself to import all of these into a lib.  Any other ideas?